# Java Spring + MongoTemplate cannot retrieve List of Object

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I had a Java Class linked to a MongoDB Collection:

```
@Document(collection = "my_collection")
public class Ev extends MyDTO{
    @Id
    private String id;
    @Indexed
    private String sessionId;
    private List<String> findings;
}
```

I had to change `findings` in this

```
    private List<MyObject> findings;
```

Declared as

```
public class MyObject {
    private String find;
    private String description;
    private int number;
    private List<SecondaryObj> details;
}
```

Here are the constructors

```
public MyObject(String find, int number) {
    super();
    this.find= find;
    this.number= number;
}

public MyObject(String find, int number, List<SecondaryObj> details) {
    super();
    this.find= find;
    this.details = details;
    this.number= number;
}
```

So in mongoDB I have a situation similar to

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b487a2667a1aa18f*******"),
    "sessionId" : "abc123mySessionId",
    "findings" : [ 
        {
            "find" : "HTTPS",
            "description" : "I found HTTPS",
            "number" : 10,
            "details": [
                {"a":"1", "b":"2"},
                {"a":"2", "b":"3"}
            ]
        },
        {
            "find" : "NAME",
            "description" : "I found name",
            "number" : 3,
            "details": [
                {"a":"1", "b":"2"},
                {"a":"2", "b":"3"}
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I obviously updated all the methods to match the new data set, but if I try to retrieve

```
Query searchQuery = new Query(Criteria.where("sessionId").is("abc123mySessionId"));
Ev result = mongoTemplate.findOne(searchQuery, Ev.class);
```

I obtain this error

```
Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate com.my.project.domain.MyObject using constructor NO_CONSTRUCTOR with arguments
```

with root cause

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: om.my.project.domain.MyObject.<init>()
```

I'm using  `spring-data-mongodb version 2.0.8` and `mongo-java-driver version 3.8.0`

I think I should declare MyObject somewhere, but I'm pretty new in Spring, so I'm trying in a kinda blind way... Any suggestion?

Comment: Could you please show constructors you have for `MyObject` class? Looks like you do not have default no-args constructor for the class.

Comment: I added them. I also see I forgot to add another field of `MyObject`, a List of other Objects defined in another Class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two non-zero-argument constructors and Spring does not know which one to call. It tries to call no-args constructor, but your class does not have that one.
Check Spring Data Mongo [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/2.0.8.RELEASE/reference/html/#mapping-conventions)

You can create no-args constructor and mark it with `@PersistenceConstructor` annotation. This way Spring calls it to create an object and sets fields via reflection based on a document fields names, so no setters are required.

Comment: Finally!
I deleted one of those constructors (which was also unused) and now it works. You made my day! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
@Document(collection = "my_collection")
public class Ev extends MyDTO{
@Id
private String id;
@Indexed
private String sessionId;
private List<MyObject> findings;}

public class MyObject {
private String find;
private String description;
private int number;}
```

In this it work fine for me in spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb - version 2.0.3.RELEASE